# Cocos2D 2.0 - programmatically selecting a CCMenuItem/CCMenuItemToggle

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have this

```
    CCMenuItem *play =
    [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"play.png"]
                            selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"stop.png"]];

    CCMenuItem *stop =
    [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"stop.png"]
                            selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"play.png"]];


    CCMenuItemToggle *stopPlayButton = 
    [CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self 
                            selector:@selector(togglePlayStop:)
                               items:Play, botaoStop, nil];


    CCMenu *togglePlayStop = [CCMenu menuWithItems:stopPlayButton, nil];
```

This is a play/stop button. It is normally showing the play image. The user taps the button, the movie plays and the button toggles to show the stop image, so the user can stop playing the movie. The movie reaches its end. The app stop playing the movie. Now I have to toggle the image on the button, to show the play image again.

How do I "tap" the button programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CCMenuItemToggle` instance has property `selectedIndex`. You can both read and write it. In your case item at index 0 will be your play button, item at index 1 will be your stop button. So it is enoough to declare your toggle in your interface, then just change `selectedIndex` property. Both

```
[m_stopPlayToggle setSelectedIndex:0];
```

and

```
m_stopPlayToggle.selectedIndex = 0;
```

will set your play button as active.

Answer (score 0):

From Cocos2d-x 3.0, the API changes to **MenuItemToggle**, the usage is like this:

```
//in SomeLayer init()
auto onItem = MenuItemImage::create(...);
auto offItem = MenuItemImage::create(...);
auto aToggle= MenuItemToggle::createWithCallback(CC_CALLBACK_1(SomeLayer::onAToggle, this), 
                                                                    onItem, //0th
                                                                    offItem, //1st
                                                                    NULL);
aToggle->setSelectedIndex(getSomeBoolValueForThisToggle()?0:1); //true to show 0th, false 1st
```